Brightcove media entity is rendering only as thumbnail
I'm trying to use Brightcove videos as media entities, like I do with YouTube embedded videos. I want the media type to just have a video url field to put the "Publish and Embed" url for the video in my Brightcove account. Doing so will render a thumbnail of the Brightcove video, but not the video player. I made sure that the media field display is set to Video, and the content field display is set to Rendered entity. Has anyone tried this with Drupal 10?

Is this information of some use? https://drupalsun.com/philipnorton42/2021/12/12/drupal-9-using-and-adding-oembed-providers
